# Dancing options popup glitch

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, manifest

In my extension (manifest v3), the options panel (which is being presented in the popup, not in a separate page) keeps glitching and "dancing".

Instead of opening in its final size, it opens in full width and shrinks slowly with a linear transition until it reaches the final size.

The problem is: when it gets near the final size, some of the inner elements get resized also, and the resizing of the inner elements makes scroll bars to appear, and this causes the popup size to grow to accommodate them; and when it grows, the inner elements reaccommodate again, the scroll bars disappear and it gets back to the shrunk size, and everything keeps "dancing" in an infinite loop:

[image: Dancing options screen]

The component code is this (the relevant styles are just below the component):

```
export default function OptionsApp() {
  const juizosUrl = googleUrls.sheetsFrontendBase + googleUrls.configSheetId;
  const diretorioUrl = googleUrls.driveFoldersBase + googleUrls.applicationFolderId;
  return (
    <main style={mainStyles}>
      <div className="form-group" style={buttonContainerStyles}>
        <Link
          label={`Baixar planilha [], mais recente, e abrir nova`}
          url={diretorioUrl}
          classes="btn btn-info"
          styles={buttonStyles}
        />
        <Link
          label="Configurações"
          url={juizosUrl}
          classes="btn btn-info"
          styles={buttonStyles}
        />
      </div>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <legend className="sisifo-v-label">
          Planilhas de hoje, {new Date().toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")}
        </legend>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <legend className="sisifo-v-label">
          Planilhas do dia anterior, {new Date().toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")}
        </legend>
      </fieldset>
      <div className="form-group">
        <Link label="Pasta com planilhas" url={diretorioUrl} />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

const mainStyles = {
  margin: "0 2rem",
  padding: "0 1rem 1rem 1rem",
  border: "solid 1px gray",
  width: "500px",
};

const buttonContainerStyles = {
  margin: "0.5rem",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
  alignItem: "center",
};

const buttonStyles = {
  width: "48%",
  textWrap: "balance",
};
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome triggered by your HTML+CSS. Try making an [MCVE](/help/mcve).